# Searching through PHP Array without knowing parts of it

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to grab data from inside of a PHP array even if I don't know everything about the array initially. For example, I've got this:

```
$currentprice = $product_info['products'][5]['price'];
```

But I don't know what that [5] there will be. Here's an example of an actual array I'm working with, which changes every time depending on what products are added to a store's shopping cart:

```
Array ( 
[5] => Array ( 
    [name] => Product 1 
    [price] => $0.07 
    [quantity] => 10 
) 
[12] => Array ( 
    [name] => Product 2 
    [price] => $0.26 
    [quantity] => 5 )
[14] => Array ( 
    [name] => $10 fee 
    [price] => 10 
    [quantity] => 1 
    [options] => Array ( ) ) 
[17] => Array ( 
    [name] => Additional Fee 
    [price] => $60.00 
    [quantity] => 5 )
```

)

Is there someway to write something like this:

```
$currentprice = $product_info['products'][*]['price'];
```

Where the [*] would act as a wildcard and look inside of the second nested array to see what the price is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only foreach loop can be use in this because the key is not something you know, its generated by PHP. Using foreach is something like this:

```
<?php 
foreach( $product_info as $product ) {
    echo $product[ 'price' ];
}
```